# File Based H2 database not working on Spring boot/Hibernate Application

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, h2

I am trying to create a h2 file based database locally but it fails when I start the application connected to it. The only file used in connecting the application to the h2 database is:

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">dbc:h2:file:./database</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">sa</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password"></property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping class = "com.example.SneakyCaloriesV2.pojo.Users"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

application.properties:

```
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

The folder structure looks something like this

```
SneakyCaloriesV2:
   src/main/java
   src/main/resources
        application.properties
        database
        hibernate.cfg.xml
```

I am getting this error:

```
2020-03-07 22:21:20.083  INFO 13492 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling    : HHH10001005: using driver [org.h2.Driver] at URL [dbc:h2:file:./database]
2020-03-07 22:21:20.084  INFO 13492 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling    : HHH10001001: Connection properties: {user=sa, password=****}
2020-03-07 22:21:20.084  INFO 13492 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling    : HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
2020-03-07 22:21:20.086  INFO 13492 --- [           main] .c.i.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl : HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
Error in creating SessionFactory object.Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
2020-03-07 22:21:20.087  WARN 13492 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactoryInitializer': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
2020-03-07 22:21:20.087  INFO 13492 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-03-07 22:21:20.087  INFO 13492 --- [           main] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed evictData of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
```

How to create a h2 file based databased properly?

Second Problem:

When using a local database, I am getting the following error upon firing a request that uses the H2:

```
Sequence "USER_ID_SEQUENCE" not found; SQL statement:
```

I created a sequence in H2 by using the following statement:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE USER_ID_SEQUENCE INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1;
```

and created the USERS table by using the following script:

```
CREATE TABLE USERS(
     ID INT PRIMARY KEY,
     USERNAME VARCHAR(50) UNIQUE,
     PASSWORD VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
     LAST_NAME VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
```

Here is my pojo mapping class:

```
package com.example.SneakyCaloriesV2.pojo;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.SequenceGenerator;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table( name = "USERS")
public class Users {
    @Id 
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "author_generator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name="author_generator", sequenceName = "USER_ID_SEQUENCE", allocationSize=1)
    @Column(name = "ID", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private int userID;

    @Column(name = "USERNAME")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "PASSWORD")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    public int getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(int userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should configure your database inside your `application.properties` or `.yml` file like the following:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./database;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
```

Your second problem might occur, as you are actually not connected to your local database and hence missing the setup of the sequences/tables